# Adding new fields to mappings requires re-indexing data in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm using elastic search 1.7.2, As i want to add new fields to existing mappings, do i need to re index entire data?

```
  Ex:
       Mappings:
                {
                     "properties":{
                          "a":{"type":string},
                          "b":{"type":string}
                       }
                }
```

If i want to add field "c", do we need to re-index entire data?. please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need to add a new field, you can simply add it, the mapping will be modified accordingly, but the field will not exist in all documents that are already indexed until you update them.

Comment: thanks for your response @Val, its ok, but my concern is, after adding new fields into mapping, will indexing  on old fields works or not.

Comment: Old fields will still be there, and nothing will change with them. You can still index document with the old fields + the new ones.